# Connect Four Program using 2D Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

These are the specs for the program I need to complete. Could someone please help me!! I really need to get this program done! Will take any help/advice I can get! Thank you all so much!

You must create two programs named Board and ConFour that have the
following criteria:

1)  Proper Introduction

2)  Comments that accurately describe the program features

3) Board should have one attribute; a two dimensional array of
character values representing the Connect Four game board. Be sure
to include a constructor (without parameters) that instantiates the 
2D-array with 6 rows and 7 columns

4) Board should contain at least four methods. The first method should
be setBoard() which adds an empty character value to every position in the board. The second method, setPosition(), should  place the character representing a player (X or O) in the column of their choosing. The third method named checkWinner() should check   the board to see if there are four of   the same character (X or O) in a row, column or either diagonal. Lastly,    printBoard(), should print the contents of the board.

5)  ConFour should  represent the game play. Have the user(s) enter

START to start the  game (they should be able to continuously play after each game)

6)  Start each turn by printing the board followed by asking the user to
enter the column they want (be sure to alternate players). If the user enters   an incorrect column number, make them re-enter. First player to get four in a row, column or either diagonal is the winner.

Comment: *Will take any help/advice I can get* - start by writing some code.

Comment: The SO ethos means you have to make an attempt yourself. You can't simply post a problem and expect someone else to do the work for you. Have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little bit of my thoughts:
To start off, try to make algorithms that check for 4 Xs/Os in a row, which should be 4 for each player. You could also just make 4 algorithms that require you to input the number you are checking for. The directions you need to check are horizontal (check `array[i][x+1]`, where i is the constant in the for loop and x is the number you find to be X or O), vertical (check `array[x+1][i]` ), right-facing diagonal (check `array[i+1][x+1]` ), and left-facing diagonal (check `array[i-1][x-1]`.

To print the board, just use 2 for loops that print the values of the array.

For the intro, use a bunch of `System.out.println()` statements.

The entering of coins is the weird part. You have to create height variables (Or a height function) that stores/checks the height of the coins, then places it on top/next to the other coin. Then check if anyone wins and move on the next player. Keep repeating it until someone wins. **Warning:** Do not use a while loop. They can't check more than one boolean at a time (but you could put a bunch of `if(check) {
boolean itsalltrue = true;
}`s, too.

Well, that's all that I can think of (I deliberately did not write the code because I would like you write your own). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a class? Did you literally just copy and paste the assignment? Try spending some time looking through the notes provided for you, or search more specific questions here. Here's an example of a similar question with code: 
[Simple 2d array java game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329900/simple-2d-array-java-game)